# Word VSTO text replacement

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working on a Word VSTO add-in. I need help with the part of it that replaces text in a document using regular expressions, as there is a behavior I don't understand.
The code looks something like this:

```csharp
var range = document.Content;
var findObj = range.Find;
findObj.ClearFormatting();
findObj.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
findObj.Execute(
  FindText: "-([0-9])",
  MatchCase: true,
  MatchWholeWord: false,
  MatchWildcards: true,
  MatchSoundsLike: false,
  MatchAllWordForms: false,
  Forward: true,
  Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue,
  Format: false,
  ReplaceWith: @"A\1",
  Replace: replaceAll
);
```

This is intended to replace hyphens in front of numbers with A, e.g., "-123" would be expected to be replaced with "A123". However, when I actually executed the code, I got "1A23".

I would like to know why this is happening and how to solve it.

(The example above is a simplified version of my code, but the nature of the unexpected behavior has not changed.)

I tried to understand the behavior in various patterns, but could not understand why it behaved this way.

Comment: Although I could not solve the problem essentially, I was able to achieve the desired behavior.
Since there were only a few target characters, such as [0-9] in the example above, I stopped using wildcards by matching each character in a loop, and it worked fine.
The problem is now solved, but I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if they can figure out the cause for future study.